# Scala code returning error with avg an abs functions

Tags: scala

While running code in Scala I'm getting the following errors with functions abs, and avg.

```
command-3092209798892765:2: error: not found: value abs
  .filter(abs(t2("engine_size") - t1("engine_size")) <= BigDecimal("0.1"))
          ^
command-3092209798892765:4: error: not found: value avg
  .agg(avg("sale_price").as("average_price")).collect()
       ^
```

The Scala code is

```
t1.join(t2, Seq("make", "model"))
  .filter(abs(t2("engine_size") - t1("engine_size")) <= BigDecimal("0.1"))
  .groupBy("registration")
  .agg(avg("sale_price").as("average_price")).collect()
```

Can you let me know if I need to import functions? Or how to fix the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` to use these functions.

Comment: Ishan, can you let me know what the function Seq() does?

Comment: `Seq()` is not a function. It is a collection. It has an apply method which takes comma separated arguments and provides you the `Seq` object.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not sure what you mean by Seq oject? I have come from a SQL background. Therefore, can you let me know the equivalent of Seq in SQL? Thanks

Comment: `Seq` is a data structure that can store multiple elements for same type. For instance, you can create `Seq[Int]` which stores multiple integers. Eg - `Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, now you can access an element by providing its index. Read it from here - https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/Seq.html

Comment: @Carltonp think of it as an alternative to List.

Comment: One last question, looking at the code can you tell me what fields it is joining tables t1, and t2 on?

Comment: The ones provided in the sequence - `"make", "model"`

Comment: So, the code is doing a join on t1.make on t2.make and t1.model on t2.model. Is that correct?